# Alert Handshake failure paypal IPN integration using fsockopen

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a problem when integrating paypal IPN to my website.
The warning is

> "Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: SSL operation failed with
>   code 1

OpenSSL Error messages:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake failure in /home/..." on this line: $fp = fsockopen
>   ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

I use fsockopen as I can only find working sample few months ago. But when I tried 2 days ago, it shown the error. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$return_url = "http://www.domain.com.au/member/payment.php";
$cancel_url = "http://www.domain.com.au/member/request.php";
$notify_url = "http://www.domain.com.au/member/payment.php";

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){            
    $querystring = '';
    $paypalQueryString = "?business=".urlencode('my-facilitator@yahoo.com')."&";

    $paypalQueryString .= "item_name=".urlencode('Item Name')."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "amount=".urlencode($totalPrice)."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "cmd=_xclick&no_note=1&lc=AU&currency_code=AUD&bn=PP-BuyNowBF%3Abtn_buynow_LG.gif%3ANonHostedGuest&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "first_name=".urlencode($niceName)."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "last_name=&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "payer_email=".urlencode($payerEmail)."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "item_number=".urlencode($accountID)."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "submit=Submit+Payment&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $paypalQueryString .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$paypalQueryString);
    //header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$paypalQueryString);
    exit();
}
else {
    //Response from Paypal
    //echo "<pre>".var_dump($_POST)."</pre>";

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']      = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']         = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']         = $_POST['custom'];

    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        echo "HTTP Error";
    } 
    else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);
        $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 2048);
        if (strpos(trim($res), "VERIFIED") !== false) {
               // update transaction --> paid status
        }
        else if (strpos (trim($res), "INVALID") !== false) {
        }
        else{
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation, but I'm using cURL instead of fsockopen.  PayPal just started requiring all connections to the sandbox be done over TLS 1.2 (and HTTP 1.1).

https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

Maybe try changing this line

> $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

to this?

> $fp = fsockopen ('tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Comment: I did, but it still have the same error. Do you think we should use https (ssl certificate) on our website?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the new CURL approach and ditch the old fsockopen way, this seems to be part of the new Paypal TLS 1.2 campaign.
I tested tls:// ssl:// and just plain https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr which all failed until I implemented the PHP Curl apprach below.

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

```
<?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: HI thanks, I have the code working in test mode (sandbox). everything completely working, but when I switch to live mode, it returns no response. there're no txn_id and txn_type. I still can't find any solution to this. Regards